# Expenses to consider for first time home buyer

Tags: first-time-home-buyer, expenses

As a first time home buyer, I'm making sure I have all of my expenses accounted for and I can afford everything I'm getting myself into.

I'm currently allocating money for:

- Mortgage
- Home Insurance
- HOA
- Taxes
- Internet
- Utilities
- Car Insurnace
- Phone expenses
- Security system
- School tuition (obtaining a master's degree while working full time)

My car is paid off so I don't have a car payment, with all of these expenses I should have enough for food and misc expenses each month.

Am I overlooking anything? I'd like an opinion from current home owners to see if they have insight on anything that a first time home buyer might not be considering.

Thanks.

Edit: The property is a newly constructed townhouse and I'd be the first to live in it. There are warranties on everything for a year, and then other pieces (windows, siding, HVAC, plumbing, etc) have warranties varying from 2 years to lifetime. So I'm hoping the time frame that I'm planning on owning this house (2-4 years) there hopefully won't be any major issues that require serious fixes.

As far as maintenance, the HOA fee covers everything outside (mowing, is really all there is) and the yard is only about as big as a slightly long double car drive way so there isn't a ton of room outside, but there is a privacy fence that each unit gets that blocks them off from their neighbors.

Comment: Are you saving money for a down payment? And I'm not sure why you're including internet, utilities, care payment, phone expenses, and tuition on that list - is this the first time you've lived on your own / paid your own expenses? If so, don't forget money for groceries, and take a look at other budgeting questions on this site.

Comment: Yes, I have some money saved for a down payment. And I lived away from home in college, but I was renting so all I had to pay for was rent, utilities and everything was included- This is the biggest reason that I'm asking this question. The money left over should be enough for food and groceries each month, and 6 months I'll not be paying for tuition so I'll have almost double the money left over during those times.

Comment: Presumably, you will have to live somewhere, so to add to Grade'Eh'Bacon's point, it may be easier to consider expenses associated only with owning a home vs renting, and then all other expenses that you would have regardless of whether you buy or rent should be categorized separately.

Comment: Allocate money for repairs/maintenance, HVAC could bomb out on day 1, so some extra cash is handy in general, but you can also budget for some maintenance, and moving expenses. Depending on what HOA covers, you may need to purchase a number of lawn-care/home maintenance tools that you don't own. I didn't think of tree-trimming before I bought my current house, that's ~$600/year for me (I'm a DIY-type, but not climbing 40-feet up to trim trees). Can be lots of little expenses in first years of home ownership for sure.

Comment: Will your furniture stand up to the move (cheap bookshelves, are cheap for good reasons) or will you need to buy pieces that are currently furnished in the rental?  Does your area typically convey appliances in home sales like dishwashers and washer/dryers or will you need to buy your own?

Comment: If you are looking for a comprehensive budget (which isn't a bad idea to figure out what you can really afford) you should probably include groceries, entertainment, and fuel as specific line items based on what you've spent in the past on them.

Comment: Are you sure it's worth the trouble to buy for two years? Imho that's the important question here. Houses don't necessarily sell instantly, so when you want to move out, there is a risk you'll not get your money for quite some time. And the risk of something breaking etc is normally calculated against it not breaking again in the next years. Renting is a lot easier to calculate and has less risk, account for the risk cost, too.

Comment: That's a minimum, I'm hoping to stay longer but it's a fairly long commute to work and depending on where I am as far as jobs go, it might be further. I do like the layouts and the area so it will all depend. I don't want to rent because it's like throwing money away imo. At the end of the month you haven't purchased anything, and plus I'm getting a good deal and it would be difficult to rent for the price I'd pay to own this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see two important things missing from your ongoing costs: maintenance and equipment. I also don't see the one-time costs of buying and moving.

Maintenance involves doing some boring math like "roofs go every 20 years or so and a new roof would cost $20k, so I need $1000 a year in the roof fund. Furnaces go every 20 years and cost $5k, so I need $250 a year in the furnace fund." etc etc. **Use your own local numbers for both how long things last and how much they cost to replace.** One rule of thumb is a percentage of the house (not house and land) price each year keeping in mind that while roof, furnace, carpet, stove, toilets etc all need to get replaced eventually, not everything does - the walls for example cost a lot to build but don't wear out - and not all at a 20 year pace. Some is more often, some is less often. I've heard 5% but think that's too high. Try 3% maybe? So if you paid $200,000 for a $100,000 house sitting on $100,000 of land, you put $3000 a year or about $250 a month into a repair fund. Then ignore it until something needs to be repaired. When that happens, fund the repair from the savings. If you're lucky, there will always be enough in there. If the house is kind of old and on its last legs, you might need to start with a 10 or 20k infusion into that repair fund.

Equipment means a lawnmower and trimmer, a snow shovel, tools for fixing things (screwdriver, hammer, glue, pliers, that sort of thing.) Maybe tools for gardening or other hobbies that house-owners are likely to have. You might need to prune back some trees or bushes if nothing else. Eventually you get tools for your tools such as a doo-dad for sharpening your lawnmower. Well, lots of doo-dads for sharpening lots of things.

One time expenses include moving, new curtains, appliances if they don't come with the house, possibly new furniture if you would otherwise have a lot of empty rooms, paint and painting equipment, and your housewarming party. There are also closing costs associated with buying a house, and you might need to give deposits for some of your utilities, or pay to have something (eg internet) installed. Be sure to research these since you have to pay them right when you have the least money, as you move in.

Comment: This is great insight, one thing I think I didn't mention in my original post and have edited to reflect: The outside is taken care of by the HOA for any mowing or tree trimming, and the yards are only as big as about a 2 car driveway. As well as the construction being brand new and I'm the first to live in it so hopefully the warranties will give me some time to save up before things start going. As far as furniture, I'm ok with like the guest bedroom being empty for a while, as long as the kitchen, master, living room, and computer room have furniture. 

Great insight, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Kate Gregory has already covered maintenance and tools.

As a one-off, there's furniture and soft furnishings for the home.

Cable/satellite TV if you want it.

You listed car insurance, but not fuel, servicing, repairs and depreciation/leasing (as applicable).

And, there's also food.

Comment: I have HBO through my phone plan (AT&T) and I only really watch Game of Thrones which has taken an extended break so I don't really care for TV otherwise. You do bring up a good point with car servicing, that's something I didn't think of. I drive ~70 miles/day for work so I have my car serviced pretty often. Thanks!